# Making a two-dimensional dictionary you can call a single value from

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

I mixed up a couple of words here and there, my bad. The example should make the intend a bit clearer than it was up to this point.

Example: 
I have .csv file named "file.csv":

```
T2Y;Brad;0001
K5;Jan;0002
T21;En;3838
T22;aps;3804
T11;Jyke;3957
T08;John;3825
K05;Tim;0001
```

And when you call my function like so:

```
>>> dict = function("file.csv")
```

you are able to call the values you ask for like so:

```
>>> dict['Brad']['code']
'T2Y'
>>> dict['John']['name']
'John'
```

What my seems to do properly is create the first dictionary by reading the .csv file, but I am unable to create a nested dictionary that can be called the way my example shows. I try to go a bit more in depth in the ramble below.

**Here is how my current code spits out the information, probably redundant information**

And my current code is a bit of a mess since I tried to form it into a nested dictionary on the fly, but what it is doing right at this point is that it opens and reads the .csv file, it splits the rows by ";" and makes a dictionary of each row that is callable by using the name as a key. What the current hurdle is, however, is that I can only call with a single key, the name, and it returns the entire row as a dictionary or something that looks the part. Like so:

```
>>> dict = function("file.csv")
>>> dict['Brad']
'T2Y;Brad;0001\n'
```

And if I try adding another key after the name key, the code stops in error code:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some code of what you've done so we can help you better?

Comment: `function[name][code]` could be used to access a value in a dictionary of dictionaries named `function`, but it's certainly not a function call. Function calls in Python use parentheses, eg `func(name, code)`.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want. What value do you expect for the dictionary entry for `function['T11']['3957']`?

Comment: Let me do some reformatting to make it a bit clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, this is a pretty simple problem: you want to create a nested dictionary with the information in a CSV file. Since you don't specify what the 3rd column is, I will just mark it as a `id` and use a string. I will also assume that the file only contains one line for each name: if not, the latest line will be used.

```
import csv

user_info = {}
with open('data.txt') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for code, name, id in data:
        user_info[name] = { 'code': code, 'name': name, 'id': id }

print (user_info)
```

This will print:

```
{'En': {'id': '3838', 'code': 'T21', 'name': 'En'}, 'Tim': {'id': '0001', 'code': 'K05', 'name': 'Tim'}, 'Jan': {'id': '0002', 'code': 'K5', 'name': 'Jan'}, 'aps': {'id': '3804', 'code': 'T22', 'name': 'aps'}, 'John': {'id': '3825', 'code': 'T08', 'name': 'John'}, 'Jyke': {'id': '3957', 'code': 'T11', 'name': 'Jyke'}, 'Brad': {'id': '0001', 'code': 'T2Y', 'name': 'Brad'}}
```

Comment: @Grak If it resolved your issue, be sure to upvote/accept the answer

Comment: I thought I did earlier, but I guess it did not register it. Done